# run two or more designers simultaneously

Tags: lotus-notes

Since R8 there is no option to run more than one instance of Domino Designer. Eclipse, at the other hand, is generous enough to run more than one instance, what is extremely useful.

Is there a way to run  another copy of designer (with different notes.ini/data directory/id) on the same computer? Virtual machine or remote connection to another computer is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, No.

You can however do it in R7. It's best also that the databases are not using any new features and the [ODS structure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21102152) is still pre-Release 8, then you can run an R7 designer. You may get warnings if the database has been updated in R8, but providing you haven't added any new R8 features to the design this message is benign. Otherwise your best bet is to run VMWare workstation, and have multiple VM's running, (or just use another PC).

Comment: accepting as answer, although I am not happy about the situation

Comment: I understand...But this hopefully saves you hours of frustration so you can work on a more effective approach to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was to say: of course, on Linux, but you'll have to wait for the Designer client to become available on Linux... ;-) So I vote Nay, I think it's not possible (at the moment).